# Sort arrays alphabetically

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array(I have to use arrays) as a new data enters the array(not add all the elements and then sort). My sorting algorithm doesn't work propely.
Instead of returning a sorted array it returns only 3 entries that are repeated a number of times.

This is what i am trying to add to the array:

```
    arrayDirectory.addEntry("Smith  RK  005598");
    arrayDirectory.addEntry("Alal KA  004567");
    arrayDirectory.addEntry("Bors OB  005678");
    arrayDirectory.addEntry("Zaaa   NZ  001234");
    arrayDirectory.addEntry("Zoll  NZ  001254");
    arrayDirectory.addEntry("Ola    KO  001245");
```

This is what it returns:

```
------PHONE DIRECTORY AS OF WED MAR 27 15:29:52 GMT 2019------
SURNAME: BORS INITIALS: OB NUMBER: 005678 
SURNAME: BORS INITIALS: OB NUMBER: 005678 
SURNAME: BORS INITIALS: OB NUMBER: 005678 
SURNAME: BORS INITIALS: OB NUMBER: 005678 
SURNAME: BORS INITIALS: OB NUMBER: 005678 
SURNAME: SMITH INITIALS: RK NUMBER: 005598 
SURNAME: SMITH INITIALS: RK NUMBER: 005598 
SURNAME: SMITH INITIALS: RK NUMBER: 005598 
SURNAME: SMITH INITIALS: RK NUMBER: 005598 
SURNAME: SMITH INITIALS: RK NUMBER: 005598 
SURNAME: ZOLL INITIALS: NZ NUMBER: 001254 
SURNAME: ZOLL INITIALS: NZ NUMBER: 001254 
SURNAME: ZOLL INITIALS: NZ NUMBER: 001254 
SURNAME: ZOLL INITIALS: NZ NUMBER: 001254 
SURNAME: ZOLL INITIALS: NZ NUMBER: 001254 
SURNAME: ZOLL INITIALS: NZ NUMBER: 001254 
SURNAME: ZOLL INITIALS: NZ NUMBER: 001254 
SURNAME: ZOLL INITIALS: NZ NUMBER: 001254 
SURNAME: ZOLL INITIALS: NZ NUMBER: 001254
```

What is the problem?

This is my addEntry method:

```
@Override
    public void addEntry(String line) {
        String[] newLine = line.split("\\s+");
        String surname, initial, number;
        if (newLine.length == 3) {
            surname = newLine[0];
            initial = newLine[1];
            number = newLine[2];

        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please fill all the required fields, [surname,initials,number]");
        }

        if (count == entries.length) {
            Entry[] tempEntries = new Entry[2 * count];
            System.arraycopy(entries, 0, tempEntries, 0, count);
            entries = tempEntries;


        } else {
            Entry entry = new Entry(surname, initial, number);


            for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < entries.length; j++)
                if (entries[j]!=null){
                    String one = entries[j].getSurname();
                    if (surname.compareToIgnoreCase(one) > 0) {
                        Entry temp = entries[i];
                        entries[i] = entries[j];
                        entries[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    entries[count]=entry;
                    count++;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

and this is my print method:

```
public void printEntries()throws NullPointerException{
    Date date=new Date();

    System.out.println("------PHONE DIRECTORY AS OF "+date.toString().toUpperCase()+"------");

    for(int i=0;i<entries.length;i++){
    if(entries[i].getSurname()==null){
    throw new NullPointerException("------END OF DIRECTORY------");
    }else{
    System.out.printf("SURNAME: %S INITIALS: %S NUMBER: %s %n",entries[i].getSurname(),entries[i].getInitial(),entries[i].getNumber());
    }
    }
    }
```

any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add the output as code instead of a link to an image

Comment: Try stepping through the code in a debugger or "play computer" with a pen/cil and paper and try figuring it out.

Comment: Have you considered using a List like ArrayList, instead of arrays ? It should be much cleaner and you could use the Collections.sort() method

Comment: Try using a `TreeSet` instead of arrays, I get arrays are nice efficient data structures but avoid such trivial tasks if there is already an appropriate data structure that does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Bargros i have to use arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `if (count == entries.length) {` is true, you are just increasing the size of array but not inserting any element. You should insert the element in both the cases. Also in the else clause, you are adding the element multiple time. `if (entries[j]!=null){` will return false multiple times and you will end up adding the element again and again.

Comment: I do not understand what i should change in the else clause can you explain further? Or show an example?